# Given two vectors, use the cross product to create a set of three orthonormal vectors

Tags: python, python-3.x, vector, compass, cross-product

Can anyone help me with this:

Given two vectors, use the cross product to create a set of three orthonormal vectors:

```
from compas.geometry import cross_vectors
from compas.geometry import angle_vectors
import math as m

v1 = [1,2,3]
v2 = [4,5,6]
```

Replace... and fill in there:

```
x1 = #...
x2 = #...
x3 = #...
print(x1)
print(x2)
print(x3)
print(m.degrees(angle_vectors(x1, x2)))
print(m.degrees(angle_vectors(x1, x3)))
print(m.degrees(angle_vectors(x2, x3)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `A` and `B`, two independent vectors, a set of 3 orthogonal vectors can be obtained like this:

`C = A x B`
`D = A x C`

`A`, `C`, `D` are orthogonal and span the 3D space

Normalize if you want an `orthonormal`:

`A/|A|`, `C/|C|`, `D/|D|`

I'll let you sort the right and left hand chirality.